# I disagree with one Rails/Rubocop convention for a practical reason. I wish to know the rationale behind this convention and if there is a better way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I like rubocop and its integration with Rails and normally honour its suggestions all the time, I can say the same about Ruby and Rails conventions it is based on.
However I really disagree with the convention below as I find it really counter-productive.

```html
agent_recorded_date = MonitorLog.joins(:connected_monitor).
                                 where('connected_monitors.id = ? AND detail = ?', replacement.replaced_monitor_id, 'Monitor event - Replace monitor error').
                                 first&.timestamp
```

This is going to be frowned by Rubocop and it is indeed not what the convention is. The way the convention goes is this:

```html
agent_recorded_date = MonitorLog.joins(:connected_monitor)
                                .where('connected_monitors.id = ? AND detail = ?', replacement.replaced_monitor_id, 'Monitor event - Replace monitor error')
                                .first&.timestamp
```

Note the place where the dots are to break the query into multiple lines to comply with coding guidelines... The first option above will cause Rubocop warning called dot position offence .
Now, imagine we want to debug this query or quickly test it in the Rails console / IRB and what we will see?

If you copy and paste the recommended way (first option above) into console it will throw en error. The second will work because if you end a line with a period IRB will assume it is a multi-line command and that will succeed.

So this is where I really disagree with Rubocop and would like to know the benefits of following the convention here and whether there is a better way of copy and paste multiline commands from IDE into rails console to test them quickly (and in case of our company it is not only a professional dev but QA people also who may need to run a specific query in a console).

Comment: This is an open question that has no concrete answer. You can try making your question in one of the many repositories they have.

Comment: Sidenote: Rails conventions dictate that this line `where('connected_monitors.id = ? AND detail = ?', replacement.replaced_monitor_id, 'Monitor event - Replace monitor error')` should be `where(connected_monitors:{id: replacement.replaced_monitor_id},detail: 'Monitor event - Replace monitor error')` Hash finders are always preferred over String based SQL even when using a substitution Array

Answer (score 1):

1. The very latest `irb` (1.3.5) [supports copy-pasting multiple lines](https://github.com/ruby/irb/pull/202)
2. If you can't upgrade yet, there is an easy way to paste a multi-line expression in irb: type an opening `(`, paste your code, then `)`.

Do not sacrifice your code for the sake of a tool's limitation. Fix the tool instead. If you still want to go against this convention, you can configure RuboCop to use `EnforcedStyle: trailing` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change rubocop's configuration using a `.rubocop.yml` configuration file.  See https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html

In this case, you want to change (or set) `EnforcedStyle: trailing`